# inkscape2tikz: exact text positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, inkscape

Take the following screenshot from Inkscape:
[image]

where the "baseline" of strings `Pa` and `pa` are snapped to the black line.

This is the LaTeX output once the graphic is converted with `inkscape2tikz`:
[image]

As you can see, with the 2nd textbox, `inkscape2tikz` uses the lowest point of the letter 'p' 
to align the text box, instead of using the actual baseline (the lowest point of the letter 'a').

Is there anyway to correct this behaviour so that texts compiled with TikZ show up exactly where they appear in Inkscape?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like this is a “bug” in `inkscape2tikz`. I doesn’t creates a `node` with the right anchor. See https://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/issues/detail?id=22.

If you want to correct this manually, try to add the `anchor=base west` option to the `node` in the resulting TikZ code. I could have a closer look if you **provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)**.

### some notes on `node`s

TikZ uses nodes to add text to a picture (and do lot of more stuff which should be outside of this answer’s scope …). The shortes way to add a node is

```
\node {Text};
```

[image: node]

This will add “Text” at (0,0), the red point indicates the anchor of the `node` that is used to align it at a certain point. A node can be part of a path too (as it is in your case, I assume).

```
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0) node {Text};
```

[image: node on path]

will add “Text” at (5,0) aligned with the center of the node. A node can have several options, here `above` (to put the node above the line), `pos` (to shift the node somewhere between the startind and ending point of the line):

```
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0) node [above,pos=0.7] {Text};
```

[image: node midway on path]

will add “Text” above of (3.5,0). As you can see TikZ automatically changes the anchor from the center to the south of the node. The gap between the line and the text is caused by the inner sep of the node, which can be shown by add the `draw` option.

```
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0) node [above,pos=0.7,draw=blue] {Text};
```

[image: node with border]

You could use `inner sep=0pt` to make the border as narrow as possible, but the won’t help for texts with descender:

```
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0) node [above,pos=0.7,draw=blue,inner sep=0pt] {My Text};
```

[image: node with descender]

In this case the descender defines the *y* value of the south anchor. To align a `node` at its baseline TikZ provides the base anchors, which can be used with the `anchor` option.

```
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0) node (n) [above,pos=0.7,draw=blue,anchor=base] {My Text};
```

[image: node with base anchor]

Note that i omit the `above` and the `inner sep` options. There are two more baseline anchors: `base west` and `base east`.

```
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0) node (w) [pos=0.1,anchor=base west,inner sep=0pt] {west}
    node (e) [pos=0.9,anchor=base east,inner sep=0pt] {east};
```

[image: nodes at east and west base]

**complete example**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[anch/.style={red,radius=1pt}]
    \draw (0,0) -- (5,0) node (n) [pos=0.7,draw=blue,anchor=base] {My Text};
    \fill [anch] (n.base) circle;
    \draw (0,-2) -- (5,-2) node (w) [pos=0.1,anchor=base west,inner sep=0pt] {west}
        node (e) [pos=0.9,anchor=base east,inner sep=0pt] {east};
    \fill [anch] (w.base west) circle;
    \fill [anch] (e.base east) circle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Topi that's very helpful. I decided to use inkscape's built in svg to pdf+tex converter for this project (deadline coming) but your instructions will be helpful once I start learning TikZ.

Comment: Your welcome! I never used such converters because I believe they output “dirty”/cluttered code – but never proofed this … I like building the code my self because I got the full control and in this case I can use all abilities PGF/TikZ provides. I guess Inkscape’s export doesn’t know how to use the `pos` options and prints the node separately or when it’s preferable to use polar coordinates or when tho use a `\foreach` or even the `intersections` library. What I want to say is that the export sure gives usable code but it’s not that flexible as hand written code.

Comment: PS: The tutorials in the TikZ manual are great to step in …